# Getting value from file and selecting the same value from dropdown using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, io, dropdown

I am facing this issue that i am trying to read from excel file and selecting the corresponding value from the dropdown on screen. Using the code:

```
cell = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(4);
cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
WebElement dr = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id =\"select2chosen-3\"]"));
dr.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[contains(.,cell.getStringCellValue())]")).click();
```

Getting this error from eclipse:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //li/div[contains(.,cell.getStringCellValue())] because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//li/div[contains(.,cell.getStringCellValue())]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: Can you share the html of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with following code,

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li/div[contains(.,'"+cell.getStringCellValue().trim()+"')]")).click();
```

Comment: did not work, getting this error ==> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //li/div[contains(.,Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods)] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//li/div[contains(.,Outdoor Gear/Sporting Goods)]' is not a valid XPath expression.

Comment: updated answer with quotes around the string. Please try.